# Filter by field in AngularDart 0.9.10

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have the following `User` class:

```dart
class User {
  String name;
  bool registered;
  User(this.name, [this.registered=false]);
}
```

In my controller, I create `users`, a list of `User` objects, some of which have the `registered` value set to `true`. How can I filter based on the `registered` property?  Here is my incomplete html:

```dart
<div ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users | filter: ????">
  {{user.name}}
</div>
```

Because of https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/800, I cannot use a predicate function. Is there a way to get a handle on the `user` variable in the filter and do a boolean filter? Something like this:

```dart
// NOT REAL CODE.
<div ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users | filter:user.registered">
  {{user.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: did you try filter:user.registered ?

Comment: Yes, that does not work. See the accepted answer for how this should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you want to use the "FilterFilter", which allows you to filer on properties of objects in a list.

```
<li ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users | filter:{registered: true}">{{user.name}}</li>
```

Full documentation is at https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-filter.FilterFilter

Second, if you need a more complicated predicate, the work-around to issue 800 is to make your predicate functions member variables instead of methods on your controller.

e.g.

```
@NgController()
class Controller {
  Function pred = (x) => shouldXByDisplayed(x);
}
```

(but expect the bug to be fixed soon!)